# Getting runtime error/crash for MP_INT in OS-less env

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am trying to use the Cyassl-1.6.5 library (TLS part) in OS-less environment.

I am getting a run-time error to `mp_int` variable which is in `integer.c` file. Can any one tell me any way to resolve this error?

Error is not during compile time, but when executing the program my MPLAB IDE crashes.

Are there any compiler settings which need to do to avoid this error?

Comment: How do you know that the crash is related to exactly one variable?

Answer (score 0):

You could try reading the generated code, to see if it does anything obviously problematic.

If your target environment supports a debugger, you should try running the programming under the debugger, to perhaps get more information about exactly where it crashes.

If the type is very large, perhaps the stack is overflowing, some embedded environments can have quite small default stacks and also sometimes don't support automatic growing of the stack frame.